# Image Analysis : Detecting corrupted and missing info images

Tags: python, image

Does anyone knows how to find out lost data and corrupted images in Python?

*Corrupted*: Frames got created but not able to read file header
*Missing info*: Frames got created with correct header info but still missing info

Comment: This question could need some more detail, maybe even a link to a corruped image. I'm assuming the question refers to frames of a video, not image files on a file system. Is that correct?

Comment: for Corrupted files it shows following error : Invalid strip byte count,strip 8.ERROR, cannot read scanline 823   . and for missing info image : it shows image without any error but some part is missing in that image. yes it is a frames of a video , i got the